# '[crit]' 398#398: *45 error - loading jpg from gphotofs mounted file system

Tags: nginx, raspberry-pi, libgphoto2

**Background:**
Busy with a project with the goal of serving jpg from a nikon d750 camera with nginx.
Physical key -> GPIO RPI -> Callback -> websocket -> client -> show jpg from:
gphotofs mounted file system.

Everything works fine as long as I don't try to load from the mounted file system, if I do I get the error:

> [crit] 398#398: *45 stat() nginx

The mounted directory is: `/var/www/html/mount/ [store_00020001/DCIM/110D7100]`
I can see all the files, so its properly mounted.

I tried:

```
chown -R 777 /var/www/html/mount
```

and:

```
adduser www-data /var/www/html/mount
```

Anyone ideas on how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this was an permissions based fault.

I ran gphotofs command from root, and tried to acces this directory via a symlink from www-data.

I solved this as followed (with using APACHE instead of NGINX):

1. changed envvar files as followed:

   sudo nano /etc/apache2/envvars

change:

```
export APACHE_RUN_USER=www-data
export APACHE_RUN_GROUP=www-data
```

to:

```
export APACHE_RUN_USER=pi
export APACHE_RUN_GROUP=pi
```

Created the symlink, and allowed apache to follow symlinks by editing conf file:

```
sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf
```

and added the following lines BETWEEN virtualhost tags:

```
<Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride Indexes
</Directory>
```

Done.